# error gedit sources.list

Tags: terminal, gedit

after saved `sources.list` with gedit, i get this error, but can update/upgrade:

```
** (gedit:2431): WARNING **: 17:40:30.625: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-language not supported
```

Comment: Hello Caesar, i wrote an answer to your question. But for your next question(s), it would be good if you describe your question (or rather the background) with more details and use formatting for log output.

Comment: Which `aspell` packages do you have installed? 
[dpkg](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/dpkg.1.html) can help you to find them.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

> (gedit:2431): WARNING **: 17:40:30.625: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-language not supported

This is just a warning, not an error. There is a difference between them.

A warning is just supposed to inform you, that something is not as expected and that you might want to look into it, to prevent an actual problem. When you see an error, it means that an actual problem occurred.

That warning you got there, in gedit, it doesn't look critical. If you feel that you can edit your files as usual, i don't see anything to worry about.

The file `/etc/apt/sources.list` is just a text file and gedit is just a text editor. I don't know what "document metadata" gedit wants to manage for that text file, it could be that gedit is trying and failed to understand the language of the file content. This doesn't affect the actual file, but if you still want to get rid of this warning, you can see if installing the english aspell package does help.

Comment: Not only sources.list after every time I edit gedit I received same output (warning)

Comment: @CaesarBhandari This is still not critical, but i rewrote the last part of the answer.